# What is the value of a global param in XSLT 1.0 if no default is set?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

We have a java web application that has XSLT 1.0 (Saxon 9.6 he) as part of it's processing. Before XML transformation takes place, the Java code populates the input XML with some extra information in it's own tag under the root tag. So something like this:

```
<root>
    <mainContentToProcess/>
    <extraInfo>
        <color>Black</color>
    </extraInfo>
</root>
```

In the XSL file, we grab that info in a global parameter, like this:

```
<xsl:param name="color" select="//extraInfo/color/text()"/>
```

The problem is, sometimes this node may not be entered in the Java code or the value is an empty string or null.

Say we set the value of color to empty string in java. In the XSL code I print out the following:

```
$color: ''
not($color): 'true'  //expected false
not($color = ''): true  //expected false
$color= '': false  // expected true
$color!= '': false
```

I can't figure out how to detect if it is an empty string. Am I missing something? The values above are not what I'm expecting. Thanks!

Java code:

```
element = doc.createElement(elementName);
element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(elementContent));
parent.appendChild(element);
```

Where elementContent is an empty string.

Comment: Saxon 9.6 HE is an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That shouldn't matter. Saxon 9 is compatible with XSLT 1.0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_XSLT

Comment: Can you show that Java code? We need to see whether you really build a (DOM?) tree with a text node that contains an empty string. Or do you set the `color` element have `textContent` as an empty string?

Comment: The title of your question: What is the value of a global param in XSLT 1.0 if no default is set? doesn't seem pertinent. You have defined a default in your select expression, and it is evaluating to an empty sequence. If you don't define a default, then the "default default" is either a zero-length string or an empty sequence, depending on the declared type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression `//extraInfo/color/text()` selects a sequence of text nodes which can be an empty sequence if there is no node selected, in that case `not($color)` is true as the boolean value of an empty sequence of nodes is `false` and the negation `true`.

Comment: Thank you Martin! I guess a more proper way of checking for an empty string would be like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310035/handling-empty-sequence-in-xslt-function

Comment: I would usually suggest to not try to select text nodes at all but to select the element node with e.g. `//extraInfo/color`. As for your sample now with the Java code, it is XSLT/XPath over DOM, I don't know how Saxon handles this, I would expect the empty DOM text node to show up as an XPath text node in the tree Saxon works with. I have added the saxon tag, perhaps @MichaelKay can tell you in more detail how Saxon wraps and represents a DOM text node with no contents in its tree.

Comment: Text nodes are never zero-length (except, as a special case, before you attach them to any element). If an element has empty content then `./text()` selects an empty sequence, not a zero-length text node. (Another reason for avoiding use of `./text()`

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes, I agree with text nodes in the XSLT/XPath data model, but a DOM Text node can exist with zero length content inside a tree, and for instance Firefox, Chrome and Edge with XPath over DOM select such a text node: http://jsfiddle.net/jew8f09d/, http://jsfiddle.net/jew8f09d/1/.

Comment: Processors evaluating XPath against a DOM, which isn't faithful to the XDM data model, are varaible as to how well they map DOM to XDM, for example DOM allows adjacent text nodes and in that case some XPath processors will happily give you two separate nodes in the result of ./text(). Saxon's general approach is to view the DOM as a valid XDM instance wherever such an interpretation is possible, and that means for example treating adjacent text nodes as a single node. This is one reason processing a DOM is slower than other tree models, and why I am always telling people to stop using DOM.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you "print out" the value, I assume you are using xsl:value-of, which converts the value supplied to a string. Now if $color is an empty sequence, which appears to be the case when the path expression selects nothing, then

$color: '' 
- yes, `string(())` is ''

not($color): 'true' 
- yes, `boolean(())` is false, and `not(())` is true.

not($color = ''): true
- yes, `(() = X)` is always false (even `() = ()` is false)

$color= '': false 
- yes, see above

$color!= '': false
- yes, `() != X` is always false

Remember that = and != are existential operators: `A~B` is true if there is some item a in A and some item b in B such that `a~b` is true. If either sequence is empty then there will be no pair of items for which the relationship holds, so the comparison is always false, giving the apparent paradox that if AUTHOR is absent, then `AUTHOR='Kay'` and `AUTHOR!='Kay'` are both false (a result very similar to SQL three-valued logic, though arrived at in a different way).